# How to change the image in picturebox based on timer?

Tags: c#, windows, timer

In my user control I'm trying to change the image in a PictureBox when the timer is stopped. But it works only for the first time. If I start the timer again the image is not updating. I used the below code to change the image.

```
public partial class CANMsgLEDControl : UserControl
{
    #region Constants
    private const int kLedOn = 2;
    private const int kLedOff = 4;
    #endregion

    private bool _blinkEnabled = false;
    private int _blinkRate = 500;        
    private GridStyleInfo _currentCell = null;       
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();       


    public CANMsgLEDControl()
    { 
    }

    public CANMsgLEDControl(GridStyleInfo cell)  
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        picBxLed.Image = imageList1.Images[kLedOff];
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);

        _currentCell = cell;            
        if (_currentCell != null)
            this.BackColor = _currentCell.BackColor;

         Create Handle
        if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            CreateHandle();
        }
    }


    #region Properties

    [Browsable(true)]
    public bool BlinkEnabled
    {
        get { return _blinkEnabled; }
        set { _blinkEnabled = value; }
    }        

    [Browsable(true)]
    public int BlinkRate
    {
        get { return _blinkRate; }
        set 
        {
            _blinkRate = value;
            _timer.Interval = _blinkRate;
        }
    } 

    #endregion   

    public void ResetLedColor()
    {
        this.picBxLed.Image = imageList1.Images[kLedOff];
    }

    public void BlinkStart()
    {
        _currentCell.BeginUpdate();

        picBxLed.Image = imageList1.Images[kLedOn];
        _currentCell.EndUpdate();            
        _timer.Start();
    }

    #region Events        

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed), new object[] { sender, e });
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.BlinkEnabled)
            {
                _timer.Stop();                    

                _currentCell.BeginUpdate();
                picBxLed.Image = imageList1.Images[kLedOff];                     
                _currentCell.EndUpdate();
            }
        }           
    }  

    #endregion

}
```

How to change the image when the timer is stopped? Can anyone suggest a way to overcome this issue?

Regards,
Arulpriya

Comment: How do you call the timer again? Is the timer `_timer_Elapsed` function executed? Is the picture update code executed and the picture does not change or the update code is not executed at all?

Comment: Why are you using `System.Timers.Timer`?  Use [System.WIndows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) so you don't have to `Invoke`.  You also need another internal boolean flag to track whether the LED is currently turned on or off.  When blink is turned on, leave the Timer on and simply toggle the state of your flag, then update the image accordingly.